# Intellij Vue project change indentation level after <script> tags

Tags: vue.js, intellij-idea

So I work in a team that predominantly uses VSCode for the front-end work, I use Intellij myself as that's what I'm comfortable with. Issue is that when I go to format the code using Intellij it adds an initial indent to the code within `<script>` and `<style>` tags, it's not the worlds biggest issue - just a bit of a pain in the arse.

Their code would look like this:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
@Component
export default class CollapsibleSection extends Vue {
    @Prop() public index: any;
    @Prop() public value: any;

    public isActive() {
        return this.index === this.value;
    }
}
</script>
```

My code would look like this:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import {Component, Prop, Vue} from 'vue-property-decorator';
    @Component
    export default class CollapsibleSection extends Vue {
        @Prop() public index: any;
        @Prop() public value: any;

        public isActive() {
            return this.index === this.value;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next major release, **2020.2**, see [WEB-30382](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-30382).

For now, please try adding both `script` and `style` to the list of **Do not indent children of** in **Settings | Editor | Code Style | HTML | Other**